# Applying animations to every instance of a UIKit class?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have some code for a simple tableview animation. Is there a way to apply this to every tableview in my project? My current project is quite large and has separate VCs and storyboards for each folder. Is there any way that I can apply changes universally?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //If transactionPage is set to -1, it's because we've reached the end of the transactions
    if transactionPage != -1 && indexPath.row == (tableData.rows(inSection: indexPath.section).count) - 1 {
        loadMoreTransactions()
    }

    if arrIndexPath.contains(indexPath) == false {
        cell.alpha = 0

        //Slide from bottom
        let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 200, 
        0)

        cell.layer.transform = transform

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, 
            initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.alpha = 1
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        })

        arrIndexPath.append(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Protocol

First possible solution is creating protocol. Create protocol and then extend it and declare method for animating your cell

```
protocol CellAnimating where Self: UITableViewDelegate {}

extension CellAnimating {

    func animateCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
        cell.alpha = 0

        let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 200, 0)

        cell.layer.transform = transform

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.alpha = 1
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        })
    }

}
```

then to view controller where you want to use this just implement this protocol and inside `willDisplay` call this method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        ...
        animateCell(cell)
        ...
    }
}

extension ViewController: CellAnimating {}
```

#### Subclassing View Controller

Second option which comes to my mind is that you can create subclass of `UIViewController` and here declare something in delegate method `willDisplay`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        ...
    }
}
```

then just set every view controller where you want to use this as subclass of `ViewController`

Comment: thanks for you answer! I've been trying to implement number 2, but could you explain in further detail how that works? All of my table views currently already inherit from a custom tableView class. If I've added the animation code into the class definition and called willDisplay function in some other VCs, but the animation is not working...

Comment: @teachMeSenpai look, you have some view controller, let's say `MyVC`. This view controller then has to inherits from `ViewController` and then when `willDisplay` method should be called in `MyVC`, it will be called. So: `class MyVC: ViewController`. Is this what you're asking for?